# How to find every combination of features shared across multiple rows?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I am pretty new to using SQL (using StandardSQL via Big Query currently) and unfortunately my Google-fu could not find me a solution to this issue.

I'm working with a dataset where each row is a different person and each column is an attribute (name, age, gender, weight, ethnicity, height, bmi, education level, GPA, etc.). I am tying to 'cluster' these people into all of the feature combinations that match 5 or more people.

Originally I did this manually with 3 feature columns where I would essentially concatenate a 'cluster name' column and then have 7 select queries for each grouping with a >5 where clause, which I then UNIONed together:

- gender
- age
- ethnicity
- gender + age
- gender + ethnicity
- age + ethnicity
- gender + age + ethnicity

^ unfortunately doing it this way just balloons the number of combinations and with my anticipated ~15 total features doing it this way seems really unfeasible. I'd also like to do this through a less manual approach so that if a new feature is added in the future it does not require major edits to include it in my cluster identification.

Is there a function or existing process that could accomplish something like this? I'd ideally like to be able to identify ALL combinations that meet my combination user count minimum (so it's expected the same rows would match multiple different clusters here. Any advice or help here would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Your current query would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If only BQ supported `grouping sets` or `cube`, this would be simple.  One method that is pretty generalizable enumerates the 7 groups and then uses bits to figure out what to aggregate:

```
select (case when n & 1 > 0 then gender end) as gender,
       (case when n & 2 > 0 then age end) as age,
       (case when n & 4 > 0 then ethnicity end) as ethnicity,
       count(*)    
from t cross join 
     unnest(generate_array(1, 7)) n
group by n, 1, 2, 3;
```

Another method which is trickier is to reconstruct the groups using `rollup()`.  Something like this:

```
select gender, age, ethnicity, count(*)
from t
group by rollup(gender, age, ethnicity);
```

Produces three of the groups you want.  So:

```
select gender, age, ethnicity, count(*)
from t
group by rollup(gender, age, ethnicity)
union all
select gender, null, ethnicity, count(*)
from t
group by gender, ethnicity
union all
select null, age, ethnicity, count(*)
from t
group by rollup (ethnicity, age);
```

The above reconstructs all your groups using `rollup()`.